# What is the Flask equivalent for server.use of node js? Also, How can I access the request object in Flask that I access in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, flask

What is the Flask equivalent for server.use of Node.js? Also, How can I access the request object in Flask that I access in Nodejs?.

server.use calls middleware in Node.Js(Code the runs before every request response.)

Comment: What does `server.use` do in node? You can access the request object directly in any flask method; just import it first `from flask import request`.

Comment: server.use calls middleware in node.js before running the main request response block. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [before_request/after_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-object).